# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/branch-A' by 12 commits

Tags: git, git-branch

This is a known problem on SO. The solution I believe is `git reset --hard origin/branch-A` (I am not 100% sure).

- I created a merge request from `branch-A` to `branch-B`. The changes got merged successfully to branch-B, no problem.
- I am currently on `branch-A`. On doing `git status` on command line, I am getting the following message:

  ```
  On branch branch-A
  Your branch is ahead of 'origin/branch-A' by 12 commits.
    (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
  ```

I am not sure where those 12 commits came from. What changes do I need to do in order to fix it?

Comment: It's not clear whether `SAR-195-FJ` is `A`or `B` here. A hard reset will obviously lose the changes you had there.

Comment: Have you pushed your changes to branch-A remote? Or did you merge locally?

Comment: @triplee updated my question. Apologies for the typo.

Comment: Did you do a squash merge when merge request was accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have 12 commits in your local repo that are not on the origin, because you haven't pushed them.

If you do `git reset --hard origin/branch-A`, you will discard those commits. We can't tell whether that's what you want.

`git log origin/branch-A..branch-A` will show you the commits that you have that haven't been pushed.

Comment: Does this command `git reset --hard origin/branch-A` will have any impact on the remote `origin/branch-A` branch ? I DON'T WANT ANYTHING TO HAPPEN in the remote `origin/branch-A branch`.

Comment: @flash `git reset` does not change the remote repository. You must use `git push` to change the remote repository.

Comment: No, the `git reset` will only affect your local repo. But you have commits in your local repo that aren't on the remote. Have you tried the `git log ...` command I suggested to see what those commits are?